# pandas to_sql postgres doplicates rows

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

While uploading data with `pandas` `to_sql` to `postgres`, the rows added are duplicated by the factor of 8.

```
print(len(df)
10000


df.to_sql(tablename, engine, index=False, if_exists='append')

test = pd.read_sql(tablename, sql.psg_engine)


print(len(test))
80000

test = test.drop_duplicates()


print(len(test))
10000
```

that happens after I add primary key and indices with the following, and it does not happen if I just send data to the table which  is newly created with to_sql. That is how I set up key and indices:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
CREATE INDEX parent ON tablename(parent);
CREATE INDEX key_value ON tablename (key,value);
```

at the same time when I run `\d table name` with postgres terminal I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column c.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi...
```

I set up `sqlalchemy` `engine` with the following string:

```
engine  = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://postgres:password@localhost:7777/bd")
```

This is my first time using postgres. Thank you!

Comment: The psql error is likely due to running an older version of psql than your postgres server.

Comment: @Jeremy, good point, can you tell  me how to update it?

Comment: You have to install a newer version.  https://www.postgresql.org/download/